# awk or sed to change column value in a file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have a csv file with data as follows

```
16:47:07,3,r-4-VM,230000000.,0.466028518635,131072,0,0,0,60,0
16:47:11,3,r-4-VM,250000000.,0.50822578824,131072,0,0,0,0,0
16:47:14,3,r-4-VM,240000000.,0.488406067907,131072,0,0,32768,0,0
16:47:17,3,r-4-VM,230000000.,0.467893525702,131072,0,0,0,0,0
```

I would like to shorten the value in the 5th column.

Desired output

```
16:47:07,3,r-4-VM,230000000.,0.46,131072,0,0,0,60,0
16:47:11,3,r-4-VM,250000000.,0.50,131072,0,0,0,0,0
16:47:14,3,r-4-VM,240000000.,0.48,131072,0,0,32768,0,0
16:47:17,3,r-4-VM,230000000.,0.46,131072,0,0,0,0,0
```

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{$5=sprintf( "%.2g", $5)} 1' OFS=, FS=, input
```

This will round and print `.47` instead of `.46` on the first line, but perhaps that is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
cat filename | sed 's/\(^.*\)\(0\.[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*\(,.*\)/\1\2\3/g'
```

So far, the output is at GNU/Linux standard output, so

```
cat filename | sed 's/\(^.*\)\(0\.[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*\(,.*\)/\1\2\3/g' > out_filename
```

will send the desired result to `out_filename`

Answer (score 1):

If rounding is not desired, i.e. `0.466028518635` needs to be printed as  `0.46`, use:

```
cat <input> | awk -F, '{$5=sprintf( "%.4s", $5)} 1' OFS=,
```

(This can another example of [Useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html))

Comment: I didn't know that about rounding, thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You want it in perl, This is it:

```
perl -F, -lane '$F[4]=~s/^(\d+\...).*/$1/g;print join ",",@F' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
16:47:07,3,r-4-VM,230000000.,0.466028518635,131072,0,0,0,60,0
16:47:11,3,r-4-VM,250000000.,10.50822578824,131072,0,0,0,0,0
16:47:14,3,r-4-VM,240000000.,0.488406067907,131072,0,0,32768,0,0
16:47:17,3,r-4-VM,230000000.,0.467893525702,131072,0,0,0,0,0
> perl -F, -lane '$F[4]=~s/^(\d+\...).*/$1/g;print join ",",@F' temp
16:47:07,3,r-4-VM,230000000.,0.46,131072,0,0,0,60,0
16:47:11,3,r-4-VM,250000000.,10.50,131072,0,0,0,0,0
16:47:14,3,r-4-VM,240000000.,0.48,131072,0,0,32768,0,0
16:47:17,3,r-4-VM,230000000.,0.46,131072,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: in Perl! thats great!, thank you so much! for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^,]+,){4}[^,]{4})[^,]*/\1/' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/([^,]{,4})[^,]*/\1/5' file
```

This replaces the 5th occurence of non-commas to no more than 4 characters length.